# how to install ForgeRock Open Identity Stack

Tags: openam

I download frstack  from 
https://github.com/wstrange/frstack#install-the-forgerock-open-identity-stack-ois

After I install Ansible and Vagrant, I don't know how to make it work

Are there any references available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Author of that project here. That is very much a work in progress - so I would not start with that.

Just get a tomcat instance running and deploy OpenAM to it. Once you understand the basics then you can look at an automated deployment using Ansible.